The appropriate robot controller
Good afternoon,
Im new to ros, started working on gazebo simulation for construction machinery, excavators in particular.
the manipulator excavator I'm trying to simulate   uses oil pressure to move the different joints.
I want to know if there is any appropriate controller that moves the joints in similar way in the gazebo simulation.
instead of moving the joints by sending a goal position i send a velocity value that movies the joint until I stop it.
thanks in advance.

uses oil pressure ... the term is hydraulic ... search for ros gazebo hydraulic

please edit your post, so that it asks a specific question

There are both position and velocity controllers available. Gazebo won't simulate the hydraulic pressure directly, but you likely will want to use torque or effort based controllers to best simulate the effects of a pressure based actuation.
Depending on how much you want to simulate the hydraulic system in your own custom plug-in. Or just approximate it in the joint efforts.
